# Remove special character from set of values in Python

Tags: python, special-characters

I want to remove a special character from a set of string values in Python.

I apply the below-mentioned logic.

I'm getting the exact output I wanted, but can anyone help me with a short and more convenient approach?

```
job = {'job', 'entrepreneur', 'student', 'services', 'housemaid', 'management', 'self- 
employed','admin.', 'blue-collar', 'technician'}
#print(job)
job_copy = set()
val = ''
for j in job:
  if j.isalnum():
    job_copy.add(j)
  else:
    for char in j:
        if char.isalnum():
            val = val+char
    job_copy.add(val)
    val = ''
print(job_copy)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'technician', 'housemaid', 'selfemployed', 'entrepreneur', 'job', 'services', 'admin', 'management', 'student', 'bluecollar'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code short and easy to follow along, you can simply use regular expression i.e `re` module in Python.
And if you haven't been introduced to regular expression before, I will suggest you read this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/regex-python/) by *real python*.
To capture any non-alphanumeric character in the string and replace it with an empty string (`""`), one can simply use `"\W"` expression which is the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` or `[^\w]` in the `re.sub()` method which can be used to substitute a regex pattern in a string with something else.

The code can be rewritten to this;

```py
import re

job = {'job', 'entrepreneur', 'student', 'services', 'housemaid', 'management', 'self-employed','admin.', 'blue-collar', 'technician'}

job_copy = {re.sub(r'\W', '', j) for j in job}

print(job_copy)
```

Output

```
{'technician', 'student', 'management', 'bluecollar', 'job', 'services', 'selfemployed', 'housemaid', 'entrepreneur', 'admin'}
```

Comment: Yeahh..this one is quite easy and understandable. Thanks, Man :)

Comment: @KRUPALIRAO If so, give an upvote or mark it as correct i.e ✅

Comment: Done @Comsavvy Sorry newbie to here also so didn't do it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter solution:

```
{re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', s) for s in job}
```

For each string `s` in `job` we substitute any special character (i.e. not an uppercase or lowercase letter) by an empty character.

Comment: Gotcha...Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and comprehension:

```
import re
output = set([re.sub('[^A-ZÜÖÄa-z0-9]+', '', s) for s in job])
```